# How do you select a list of objects with composite keys?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Currently using Eclipselink JPA 2.4.2 and have a bunch of objects stored in the database using a composite key via the @IdClass method, i.e:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ThingsPK.class)
public class MyBunchOfThings {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator="ID_SEQ")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="ID_SEQ")
   private Integer id;

   @Id
   private Date timestamp;

   ...

}

public class ThingsPK {

   private Integer id;

   private Date timestamp;

}
```

If I need to select a few of these things via a select in clause, how do I do this via JPQL with the composite primary key?

e.g.

```
List<ThingsPK> keyList = ...
TypedQuery<MyBunchOfThings> query = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM MyBunchOfThings t WHERE t.??? IN :keyList", MyBunchOfThings.class);
query.setParameter("keyList", keyList);
List<MyBunchOfThings> foundThings = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Why do you need also an @Id over timestamp? I mean why didn't you leave it only with the Integer?

Comment: We're using Oracle partitioning on timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `IN` JPQL operator, then use [@EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html). Otherwise use the AND/OR in your query, something like:

```
SELECT t FROM MyBunchOfThings t WHERE (t.id=:id1 AND t.timestamp=:ts1) OR (t.id=:id2 AND t.timestamp=:ts2) OR...
```

Alternatively you might try the following query:

```
List<ThingsPK> keyList = ...
TypedQuery<MyBunchOfThings> query = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM MyBunchOfThings t WHERE t IN :keyList", MyBunchOfThings.class);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have specified we're tied to the IdClass as the Integer id is a sequence and these don't seem to get updated when using EmbeddedId/Embeddable. Is this AND/OR the only way with IdClass?

Comment: I am not an expert, but at the moment I don't see other possibilities to do that.